# Unmatched dependent samples - what to do?

Tags: anova, sample

Yes, I know it's a big design flaw, but I'm analyzing data from the same sample collected over time (change in mean scores), but data are not matched by ID. What are my options? Will using ANOVA with time as the grouping variable with dependent samples only effect power (creating last of power) or also other statistical estimates such as effect size or F? The between subjects effects are really within subjects, but the data can't be fixed. Any analysis and reporting advice? Thanks!

Comment: Need more information about data in order to help.

Comment: There are 3 time measurements, each 6 months apart, on one group that are not matched over time. So, time is categorical as pre-post-followup. The dependent variable is measured on a 5 point scale.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25941/t-test-for-partially-paired-and-partially-unpaired-data (and a lot of posts linked on that page)

Answer (score 1):

Difficult question. I would try simple things first, like the [Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test). However, caution because treatment of ties needs correction, see link [Kolmogorov-Smirnov vs Mann-Whitney U When There Are Ties](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127027/kolmogorov-smirnov-vs-mann-whitney-u-when-there-are-ties). That would allow one to check if {A,B} {B,C} and {A,C} suggest significant differences. Using ANOVA might be tricky, as doing regression on three factors, {A,B,C} that are not continuous variables might be hard to interpret.